# Error: Type 'TableMetadata' not found | FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter and I am facing this issue that after cleaning the build (flutter clean) my code stopped working and it is stuck in build failed..

I tried deleting the flutter SDK and doing that process again but still I am getting the same error messages.

I was trying to fix the Firebase login and replaced the 'google-services.json' file and then after these commands flutter [clean build, pub get and pub upgrade] the code is stuck in build.

(this is the error message and the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJEPd.jpg))

```html
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widget_from_html-0.5.1+5/lib/src/widget_factory.dart:60:57: Error: Type 'TableMetadata' not found.
  Widget buildTable(BuildMetadata m, TextStyleHtml tsh, TableMetadata data) =>
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widget_from_html-0.5.1+5/lib/src/internal/layout_grid.dart:7:24: Error: Type 'TableMetadata' not found.
    TextStyleHtml tsh, TableMetadata data) {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widget_from_html-0.5.1+5/lib/src/widget_factory.dart:60:57: Error: 'TableMetadata' isn't a type.
  Widget buildTable(BuildMetadata m, TextStyleHtml tsh, TableMetadata data) =>
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widget_from_html-0.5.1+5/lib/src/internal/layout_grid.dart:7:24: Error: 'TableMetadata' isn't a type.
    TextStyleHtml tsh, TableMetadata data) {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       376.2s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to search for this build failed issue but I can't get to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app's pubspec.yaml file look for this line: flutter_widget_from_html and use the version ^ 0.5.1 + 3

Ex: flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.5.1+3

Then click on pub upgrade and run your app

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly by downgrading the package as you said

Answer (score 1):

"The easiest fix is to run `flutter pub upgrade` to make sure both `flutter_widget_from_html` and `flutter_widget_from_html_core` is updated together."

Before upgrading pub, you should constrain the newest package version in the `pubspec.yaml` as `flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.5.2`

For credit and more info [see here](https://github.com/daohoangson/flutter_widget_from_html/issues/435)